# Form design is not rendering correctly in Browser while it looks good in visual studio design

Tags: html, css, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

Why is ASPX HTML page not rendering correctly. If i go to the Design Window in VS the CSS code are displayed correctly but if i use the Browser (IIS Express Opera) the buttons are rendering at wrong position.

I used Css to make the button float left or right in a Div-Box.

Design in Visual Studio 2019[image]

how it looks in browser:
[image]

Code:

```
CSS
.div1 {
    background-color: red;
    width: 800px;
    height: 100%;
}

#ListPersonen {
    float: right;
}


.Fright {
    float: right;
}

.Fleft {
    float: left;
}

H3 {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


SiteMaster:
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="NetTest.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - Mannschaftsverwaltung</title>
    <link href="~/Css/MVStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" runat="server"/>
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>

    <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link href="~/Css/MVStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" runat="server"/>
</head>
```

ASPX (HTML)

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/View/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Mannschaftsverwaltung.aspx.cs" Inherits="NetTest.View.Mannschaftsverwaltung" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

   <h1>Mannschaftsverwaltung - Teams</h1> 
    <asp:Label ID="infoLabel" runat="server" Text="" Visible="false" ForeColor="Green" Font-Size="15"></asp:Label>
    <br /> 
  <h3> Mannschaften: </h3>
   <asp:ListBox ID="listMannschaften" runat="server" Width="200px" Height="75px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="listMannschaften_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:ListBox>
   <br /> <br />
   <div class="div1">
   <div class="Fleft">
   <h3> Personen (Mannschaft) </h3>
   <asp:ListBox ID="ListPersonen" runat="server" Height="200px" Width="300px" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:ListBox>
   </div>
   <div class="Fright">
   <h3>Personen (Verfügbar) </h3>
   <asp:ListBox ID="ListVerfügbar" runat="server" Height="200px" Width="300px" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:ListBox>
   </div> </div> <br />
   <div class="div1">
   <div class="Fleft">
   <asp:Button ID="btn_del" runat="server" Text="Entfernen" Height="35px" Width="150" OnClick="btn_del_Click"/> 
   </div>
   <div class="Fright">
   <asp:Button ID="btn_add" runat="server" Text="Hinzufügen" Height="35px" Width="150" OnClick="btn_add_Click"/>
   </div> 
   </div>
   <h1>Mannschaftsverwaltung - Hinzufügen</h1> <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox> <br /> <br />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem>Fussball</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Tennis</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Handball</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList> <br /> <br />
    <asp:Button ID="BtnAdd" runat="server" Text="Hinzufügen" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
</asp:Content>
```

Woud be nice if someone can help :)

Thanks alot

**UPDATE:
I solve the problem by changing the Divbox Height from 100% to 250px!**

```
.div1 {
    background-color: red !important;
    width: 800px;
    height: 270px;
}

.div2 {
    background-color: blue !important;
    width: 800px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: where is MainContent in master?

Comment: Nope in another ASPX site thats using the master file.

Comment: The visual HTML designer in Visual Studio is horribly ancient and broken - **don't use it** and especially don't rely on it for your website design. The code behind the visual HTML designer has not been significantly updated since Visual Studio 2010 - it's over 10 years old now (a lifetime in web-years!) and it does not support any modern HTML5 or CSS3 - there's a reason why Visual Studio does not show a visual-designer for non-ASP.NET WebForms files (when I was at Microsoft, my manager used to work on the visual designer and he shared his horrifying war-stories with me, that alone put me off!

Comment: Please don't edit your solution into your question. Instead, add an answer to your question explaining what you did to solve the problem. Note that I don't see a reference to the `div2` class in the HTML presented in the question; so it you added or modified the HTML, be sure to call that out in your answer.